# Using SSIS, any good tutorials

Tags: ssis

I was look for a good resource to learning SQL Server business Studio and in particular SSIS packages, any sugguestions?

Comment: I would be interested in this as well.  Sadly I haven't found anything beyond the very very basics myself (i.e. not enough for any sort of real-world scenario)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- There is an ongoing 'Stairway' series at SQLServerCentral.com - I believe you'll need to sign up at the site (free) to view it:  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72494/

MSDN is always a good resource, here are a couple of good links:

- Designing Packages in Business Intelligence Development Studio : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141711.aspx
- Designing and Implementing Packages Tutorials: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms167031.aspx
- Tutorial: Deploying Packages: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365338.aspx
- Integration Services Videos: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd299421.aspx

Having been through this recently - I suggest getting your hands dirty as soon as possible and then google the various tools you *think* you need until you find the one you actually do need.  You'll build up your knowledge along the way, and I find that finding out why a tool is the *wrong* tool for a job helps me get an a better understanding of why it might the right tool later on.